# oninput to calculate total for multiple rows in html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i am trying to calculate the total price for each new item added. I have created an onchange function that will calculate the total price based on the quantity inputted by the user, so every time the user changes the quantity, the price changes. I have tried running my code however it doesn't seem to be calculating and displaying the total in its corresponding text box.

```js
function getTotal($i){
   var price = document.getElementById('priceper_'+$i+'').value;
   var per_pack = document.getElementById('per_pack_'+$i+'').value;
   var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity_'+$i+'').value;
   document.getElementById('subtotal_'+$i+'').value = ((price/per_pack)*quantity);
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>Paper</td>
<td align="center">Price</td>
<td align="center">Per Pack</td>
<td align="center">Quantity</td>
<td align="center">Sub Total</td>
</tr>
<tr class="multipp">
<td><input type="text" name="description_0" id="description_" size="85" maxlength="70" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($description[0]); ?>" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="priceper_0" id="priceper_" size="10" maxlength="9" value="" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="per_pack_0" id="per_pack_" size="10" maxlength="9" value="" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="quantity_0" id="quantity_0" size="10" maxlength="9" onChange="getTotal(<?php echo $i;?>);"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="subtotal_0" id="subtotal_" size="15" maxlength="9" value="" /></td>
</tr>
<?php
for($i=1; $i<10; $i++)
{
  echo '<tr class="multipp">';
  echo '<td><input type="text" name="description_'.$i.'" id="description_'.$i.'" size="85" maxlength="70" value="'.htmlspecialchars($description[$i]).'" /></td>';
  echo '<td><input type="text" name="priceper_'.$i.'" id="priceper_'.$i.'" size="10" maxlength="9" value="'.htmlspecialchars($priceper[$i]).'" /></td>';
  echo '<td><input type="text" name="per_pack_'.$i.'" id="per_pack_'.$i.'" class="txt" size="10" maxlength="9" value="'.htmlspecialchars($priceper[$i]).'" /></td>';
  echo '<td><input type="text" name="quantity_'.$i.'" id="quantity_'.$i.'" size="10" maxlength="9" onChange="getTotal('.$i.');" value="'.htmlspecialchars($quantity[$i]).'" />`</td>';
  echo '<td><input type="text" name="subtotal_'.$i.'" id="subtotal_'.$i.'" size="15" maxlength="9" value="'.htmlspecialchars($subtotal[$i]).'" /></td>';
  echo '</tr>';
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Please replace your PHP with HTML in a [mcve] in your snippet. Snippets should run to show the issue

Comment: please for example?

Comment: i have to print multiple rows so i use php

Comment: I know, but the snippet does not run PHP. So repeat the first row and change the names and IDs from 0 to 1 (you are missing _0 on some of the IDs now

Comment: manually we can set unique id of each rows but what i should in do for print multiple rows in php

Comment: What you are doing now in the PHP seems correct. See my answer for the JavaScript part. You do not need to have the onchange on the input. Instead add onKeyUp to all quantity fields to have the complete form recalculate

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```js
function getTotal() {
  var total = 0;
  for (var i=0,n=document.querySelectorAll(".multipp").length; i<n;i++) {
    var price = document.getElementById('priceper_'+i).value;
    var per_pack = document.getElementById('per_pack_'+i).value;
    var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity_'+i).value;
    var subtotal = (price/per_pack)*quantity;
    document.getElementById('subtotal_'+i).value=subtotal.toFixed(2);
    total+=subtotal;
  }    
  document.getElementById("total").value=total.toFixed(2);
}
window.onload=function() {
  for (var i=0,n=document.querySelectorAll(".multipp").length; i<n;i++) {
    document.getElementById('quantity_'+i).onkeyup=getTotal;
  }
  getTotal();
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>Paper</td>
<td align="center">Price</td>
<td align="center">Per Pack</td>
<td align="center">Quantity</td>
<td align="center">Sub Total</td>
</tr>
  <!-- here you loop in your PHP from 0 to 9 if you want 10 fields -->
<tr class="multipp">
<td><input type="text" name="description_0" id="description_'" size="85" maxlength="70" value="desc 0" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="priceper_0" id="priceper_0" size="10" maxlength="9" value="11" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="per_pack_0" id="per_pack_0" size="10" maxlength="9" value="1" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="quantity_0" id="quantity_0" size="10" maxlength="9" value="0"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="subtotal_0" id="subtotal_0" size="15" maxlength="9" value="0.00" /></td>
</tr>
<tr class="multipp">
<td><input type="text" name="description_1" id="description_1" size="85" maxlength="70" value="desc 1" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="priceper_1" id="priceper_1" size="10" maxlength="9" value="22" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="per_pack_1" id="per_pack_1" size="10" maxlength="9" value="2" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="quantity_1" id="quantity_1" size="10" maxlength="9" value="0"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="subtotal_1" id="subtotal_1" size="15" maxlength="9" value="0.00" /></td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan=4>&nbsp;</td><td><input type="text" id="total" value="0.00" />
</table>
```

The PHP:

```
<?php
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++)
{
  echo '<tr class="multipp">';
  echo '<td><input type="text" name="description_'.$i.'" id="description_'.$i.'" size="85" maxlength="70" value="'.htmlspecialchars($description[$i]).'" /></td>';
  echo '<td><input type="text" name="priceper_'.$i.'" id="priceper_'.$i.'" size="10" maxlength="9" value="'.htmlspecialchars($priceper[$i]).'" /></td>';
  echo '<td><input type="text" name="per_pack_'.$i.'" id="per_pack_'.$i.'" class="txt" size="10" maxlength="9" value="'.htmlspecialchars($priceper[$i]).'" /></td>';
  echo '<td><input type="text" name="quantity_'.$i.'" id="quantity_'.$i.'" size="10" maxlength="9" value="'.htmlspecialchars($quantity[$i]).'" />`</td>';
  echo '<td><input type="text" name="subtotal_'.$i.'" id="subtotal_'.$i.'" size="15" maxlength="9" value="'.htmlspecialchars($subtotal[$i]).'" /></td>';
  echo '</tr>';
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks but i have to print multiple rows through php. than what i can do

Comment: The JavaScript code does not care. I now loop over whatever many multipp rows there are in the table

Comment: if i use php than only one row output is generated

Comment: What are you talking about??? I am not looking at your PHP. You have a JavaScript issue - I fix the JavaScript issue. How you generate the table is irrelevant unless you have PHP errors

Comment: javascript is ok but what i should do in php input tag

Comment: Please see my update. It is now complete I believe - the statement `for (var i=0,n=document.querySelectorAll(".multipp").length; i<n;i++) {` looks at all the rows generated by the php